# Why the following two Julia codes gave different answers?

Tags: julia

Version 1:

```
A=[1 2;3 4]
for ii in 1:3
  B=A
  B[:,:]=B[:,:].+1
end
display(A)
```

Version 2:

```
A=[1 2;3 4]
for ii in 1:3
  B=A
  B=B.+1
end
display(A)
```

Version 1 gives

```
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  5
 6  7
```

Version 2 gives

```
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

I think it has to do with reference and copy. In which step is a copy created in version 2? Thank you if anyone could answer.

I expect version 1 and 2 should give identical answers. I looked up the reference manual but still don't understand when a copy is created in version 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B.+1` creates a copy in both instances. Call this copy `X`

In version 1, `B[:,:]=` mutates in-place the data associated with `B` to be equal to `X`. It just so happens that the data associated with `B` is exactly the data associated with `A`, which is why you see `A` change.

Version 2 reassigns the variable `B` itself to instead have its associated data be `X` rather than `A`. This is why `A` does not change.

If you want to avoid creating a copy altogether, you can write this as `A .+= 1`

Comment: To be accurate: at no point is any copy made in either of the versions. But in version 2 a new temporary array is created. This temporary array is not a copy of anything, but contains the values `B.+1`